# Magento 2 - On category save 'URL key for specified store already exists' error occurred

Tags: magento2, category, migration, url-key

After migration process, I can not save category page.

I try all solution but not getting the success it gives an error 
like below image.

http://prntscr.com/irfiml

Comment: Only require changing URL key for the category. Because URL is unique for all. If you change your URL key after that you can't get this type of error. **@jigs**

Comment: try this but not work for me

Comment: Please check stores wise URL key for that category. you get duplicate URL key.

Comment: no i fond only single url for single store in catalog_category_entity_varchar table

Comment: Check your URL in `url_rewrite` table. And find it is multiple in table or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the duplicate url key entries in **'url_rewrite'** table for that store_id. Check by deleting that category entry from **'url_rewrite'** table.

This issue mostly occurs in multi store websites.